# Move text baseline in <li> 2 px up

Tags: html, css, menu, html-lists, mousehover

I have implemented my webpage menu by inline `li`-s of `ul`. `li` has a colored border and contains `a`. Now `onmousehover` I need to change color of the text inside `a` and move it `2px` up by not moving the `li` border. How can I do that?

Comment: By changing the top and bottom padding of the `a` link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to remove the top padding a bit and increase the bottom padding a bit to maintain the markup integrity.

I have set up a simple example of what you want. Check it on the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KwNKw/)

The HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

The CSS:

```
ul { width: 200px; margin: 20px; }
li { border-top: 2px #000 solid; padding: 5px; }

li a { padding: 5px; display: inline-block; }
li:hover a { padding: 3px 5px 7px 5px ; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your CSS:

```
a:hover.jump {
            color: [Insert whatever];
            position: relative;
            bottom: 2px;
}
```

And then add a class to your link

```
<ul>
<li><a href="http://google.com" class="jump">My Link Text</a></li>
</ul>
```

You can add background colors or whatever else you need on the hovering text. The cliche-named but pretty useful website [CSS Ninja](http://www.thecssninja.com/xhtml/advanced-hover-css) has a bunch of examples